# How to use a conditional statement to perform an action if a string comes after a particular string in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Hi I am wanting to hide the two 0's if a user enters a number after the decimal point. When a user enters the decimal the two 0's will show as some sort of placeholder but when the user enters a 1 digit number after the decimal only one "0" place holder will show and if they enter another another the placeholders will disappear. Similar to CashApp when you type in a decimal to send money.

"amountRequested.amount" is a string but is converted to an int or float when the user clicks the pay button.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AmountView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var amountRequested: amountRequested
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("$\(amountRequested.amount)")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .bold()
                .font(.system(size: 50))
            
            Text(amountRequested.amount.contains(".") ? "00" : "")
                .foregroundColor(Color(.white).opacity(amountRequested.amount.contains(".") ? 0.4 : 2.0))
                .bold()
                .font(.system(size: 50))
        }
    }
}
```

https://postimg.cc/1gtdH88y
https://postimg.cc/87w3MRPy

Comment: You should be using NumberFormatter instead of trying to implement your own logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will put you in the right direction I think.

```swift
@ObservedObject var amountRequested: Amount
@State var userInput:String = ""

private func updatedTexts()->(String,String)?{
    let requestedValues = userInput.split(separator: ".")
 
    var wholeValue = ""
    if let whole = requestedValues.first {
        wholeValue = String(whole)
    }
    var decimalValue = ""
    if requestedValues.count > 1 {
        decimalValue = String(requestedValues[1])
    }
            
    var leftValue = ""
    var rightValue = ""
    
    switch (wholeValue.count, decimalValue.count) {
    case (let whole, 0):
        if whole == 0 { // nothing is inserted yet
            leftValue = userInput
        }
        else {
            leftValue = userInput
            rightValue = "00"
        }

    case (_, 1):
        leftValue = userInput
        rightValue = "0"
    case (_, 2):
        leftValue = userInput
        rightValue = ""
    default:
        break
    }
    
    return (leftValue, rightValue)
}
```

Then in the body, you use this function as:

```swift
if let texts = updatedTexts() {
    HStack {
        Text(texts.0)
            .bold()
            .font(.system(size: 50))
            .foregroundColor(
                Color(.white).opacity(2)
            )
        Text(texts.1)
            .bold()
            .font(.system(size: 35))
            .foregroundColor(
                Color(.white).opacity(0.3)
            )
    }
}
```